# How to execute the PL/SQL code stored in .sql files using cx_Oracle and Python

Tags: python, database-connection, cx-oracle

My requirement is to execute the PL/SQL code stored in multiple .sql files using python.

My assumtion was "curs.execute(sql_command)" would work but problem is I have to pass the input parameters as well to the procedure.

Please let me know how to execute the Stored Procedures stored in .sql files using python, also all the Stored Procedures are stored in separate files i.e each file contain only one stored procedure.

Comment: If the answer below doesn't help, please clarify what you mean by "I have to pass the input parameters as well to the procedure".

Comment: The cx_Oracle user doc on using PL/SQL is at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html

Answer (score 0):

If each stored procedure is stored in a separate .sql file, it is fairly straightforward:

```
sql = open(fileName).read()
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user/password@dsn")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Note, however, that if the SQL stored in the file contains a trailing slash (/) you will need to remove that first. Likewise, if the SQL stored in the file is not a stored procedure but a create table statement, for example, you will need to strip the trailing semicolon (;).

If you need to call the stored procedure that can be done as follows:

```
cursor.callproc("TheProcedureName", (arg1, arg2, arg3))
```